# ansible meta: refresh_inventory does not include previously absent hosts in task execution

Tags: networking, automation, ansible, refresh, inventory

Sometime ago, somebody suggested using dynamic inventories to generate a different hosts file depending on a location and other variables from a template, but I faced a pretty big issue :

After I create the inventory from a template, I need to refresh it (I do it using meta: refresh_inventory) for Ansible to execute tasks on newly added hosts, however, if the host was not initially in hosts file, ansible does not execute tasks on it. On the other hand, if after changing the host file a host is absent from a newly-formed file, then Ansible omits the host like it should, so the refresh_inventory does half of the work. Is there any way to get around this issue?

E.g. I have 1 task to generate hosts file from template, then refresh inventory, then do a simple task on all hosts, like show message:

```
 tasks:
  - name: Creating inventory template
    local_action:
         module: template
         src: hosts.j2
         dest: "/opt/ansible/inventories/{{location}}/hosts"
         mode: 0777
         force: yes
         backup: yes
    ignore_errors: yes
    run_once: true

  - name: "Refreshing hosts file for {{location}} location"
    meta: refresh_inventory

  - name: Force refresh of host errors
    meta: clear_host_errors

  - name: Show message
    debug: msg="This works for this host"
```

If initial hosts file has hosts A, B, C, D, and the newly created inventory has B, C, D, then all is good:

```
ok: [B] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
ok: [C] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
ok: [D] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
```

However, if newly formed hosts file has hosts B, C, D, E (E not being present at initial hosts file) then again the result is:

```
ok: [B] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
ok: [C] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
ok: [D] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
```

With task for E missing. Now if I replay the playbook, only to add another host, say F, then the result looks like:

```
ok: [B] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
ok: [C] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
ok: [D] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
ok: [E] => {
    "msg": "This works for this host"
}
```

But no F, which is already added to the inventory file before the refresh.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Post the code of how to test "`if the host was not initially in the hosts file, Ansible does not execute tasks on it`". Make it [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I updated my initial post with code and examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [Basics](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics)

> For each play in a playbook, you get to choose which machines in your infrastructure to target ... The hosts line is a list of one or more groups or host patterns ...

For example, it is possible to create the inventory in the 1st play and use it in the 2nd play. The playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: hosts.j2
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/hosts"
    - meta: refresh_inventory

- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

with the template (fit it to your needs)

```
$ cat hosts.j2
[test]
test_01
test_02
test_03

[test:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
ansible_perl_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/perl
```

give

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [template] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY [test] *********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************
ok: [test_02]
ok: [test_01]
ok: [test_03]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_01"
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_02"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_03"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_01                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_02                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the first answer provided here is correct I think this deserves an explanation on how `refresh_inventory` and also `add_host` behave. As I've seen a few other questions regarding this topic.

It does not matter if you use static or dynamic inventory, the behavior is the same. The only thing specific for dynamic inventory that can change the behavior is caching. **The following applies for disabled caching or refreshed cache after adding the new host.**

Both `refresh_inventory` and `add_host` allow you to execute tasks only in **subsequent plays**. However they allow you to access `hostvars` of the added hosts also in the current play. This behavior is partially and very briefly mentioned in the [add_host documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) and is easy to miss.

> Use variables to create new hosts and groups in inventory for use in **later plays** of the same playbook.

Consider following inventory called `hosts_ini-main.ini`:

```
localhost testvar='testmain'
```

Now you can write a playbook that will observe and test the behavior of `refresh_inventory`. It overwrites `hosts_ini-main.ini` inventory file (used by the playbook) with the following contents from the second file `hosts_ini-second.ini`:

```
localhost testvar='testmain'
127.0.0.2 testvar='test2'
```

The playbook prints `hostvars` before the inventory is changed follows by changing the inventory, refreshing inventory, again printing `hostvars` and then trying to execute task only on the newly added host.

The second play also tries to execute task only on the added host.

```
---
  - hosts: all
    connection: local
    become: false
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
      - name: Print hostvars
        debug:
          var: hostvars
      
      - name: Print var for first host
        debug:
          var: testvar
        when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['testvar'] == "testmain"

      - name: Copy alternate hosts file to main hosts file
        copy:
          src: "hosts_ini-second.ini"
          dest: "hosts_ini-main.ini"

      - name: Refresh inventory using meta module
        meta: refresh_inventory

      - name: Print hostvars for the second time in the first play
        debug:
          var: hostvars

      - name: Print var for added host
        debug:
          var: testvar # This will not execute
        when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['testvar'] == "test2"

# New play
  - hosts: all
    connection: local
    become: false
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
      - name: Print hostvars in a different play
        debug:
          var: testvar
        when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['testvar'] == "test2"
```

Here is the execution (I've truncated parts of the output to make it more readable).

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************

TASK [Print hostvars] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars": {
        "localhost": {
            "ansible_check_mode": false,
            "ansible_config_file": "/home/john/dev-ansible/ansible.cfg",
            "ansible_diff_mode": false,
            "ansible_facts": {},
            ...
            "testvar": "testmain"
        }
    }
}

TASK [Print var for first host] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "testvar": "testmain"
}

TASK [Copy alternate hosts file to main hosts file] ***************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Refresh inventory using meta module] ************************************************

TASK [Print hostvars for the second time in the first play] *******************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars": {
        "127.0.0.2": {
            "ansible_check_mode": false,
            "ansible_config_file": "/home/john/dev-ansible/ansible.cfg",
            "ansible_diff_mode": false,
            "ansible_facts": {},
            ...
            "testvar": "test2"
        },
        "localhost": {
            "ansible_check_mode": false,
            "ansible_config_file": "/home/john/dev-ansible/ansible.cfg",
            "ansible_diff_mode": false,
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
            },
            ...
            "testvar": "testmain"
        }
    }
}

TASK [Print var for added host] ***********************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************

TASK [Print hostvars in a different play] *************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
ok: [127.0.0.2] => {
    "testvar": "test2"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************
127.0.0.2                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As can be seen the `hostvars` contain information about the newly added host even in the first play, but Ansible is not able to execute task on the host. When new play is created the task is executed on the new host without problems.

Comment: "However they allow you to access hostvars of the added hosts also in the current play."  That is not working with the AWS inventory plugin right now.